# Web deployment to Azure VM failed

Tags: c#, azure

I am currently following the tutorial [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/AspNetVMs/docs/publish-web-app-from-visual-studio.md) 
to deploy an ASP.NET app to my Azure VM using Visual Studio. There are two pre-requisites listed for the tutorial; I fulfill them both.

Unfortunately, I keep encountering this error:

> Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer
>   ("XXX.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com") using the specified process
>   ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make
>   sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the
>   remote computer.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)

Running the command `net start wmsvc` gives me the following response:

`The requested service has already been started.`

When I run `netstat -an`, I can verify that Port 8172 (to which I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET app) is listening:

> TCP    0.0.0.0:8172           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

I have also ensured that there is an inbound security rule inside my firewall to allow all connections to Port 8172 via TCP. On my Azure portal, I have added the same security rule too.

Any ideas on how I may fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of trial and error (along with copious amounts of Googling), I managed to fix the issue.

The information provided by the tutorial [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/AspNetVMs/docs/publish-web-app-from-visual-studio.md) is incomplete/inaccurate. It is not sufficient to install `Web Deploy` simply by following the instructions given -- in fact, the claim that "Once Web Deploy is installed, the Web Management Service is started and set to **automatic startup**" (my emphasis) is false. Here is a screenshot taken from the `IIS` tab in `Server Manager`:

[image]

As you can see, the `Start Type` of `Web Management Service` is `Manual`.

After downloading and installing `Web Deploy 3.6`, one has to go to `Programs and Features`, find `Microsoft Web Deploy`, and then right-click and select `Change`. Click `Next` on the first page, then `Change` on the second page, and one will come across this window:

[image]

Make sure that both `IIS 7 Deployment Handler` (as well as everything beneath it) and `Remote Agent Service` are selected.

Once that is done, when one navigates to `Server Manager` and click on the `IIS` tab, one will see that both the `Web Management Service` and the `Web Deployment Agent Service` are now running automatically:

[image]

Having done all these, one can now deploy an ASP.NET app directly on an Azure VM.

Answer (score 1):

you are probably missings and Azure Network Security Group (NSG) rule to allow such traffic to the vm, one way to test this is do something like this from your workstation:

```
Test-NetConnection XXX.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com -Port 8172
```

if that doesnt work, your NSG is blocking the traffic (most likely). You can consult [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal) article to open ports on NSG.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I ran the command and was able to establish a TCP connection: https://pasteboard.co/I7lXAwkj.png

Comment: according to the link, port 80 should also be working

Comment: I am able to establish TCP connections to Port 80 and Port 8172 on my Azure VM. Web Management Service is also started on my Azure VM. And yet, I cannot deploy my ASP.NET app to my Azure VM on Port 8172. :-(

Comment: just reboot it ;)

Comment: I will try, and let you know whether it is working ASAP.

Comment: I have rebooted my Azure VM, and still see the same error message.

Comment: ugh. i'm out of ideas. can you try doing the same from within the virtual network? another thing to try, remove nsg from the vm\vnet completely

Comment: I see the same error message even when trying to deploy the web app directly on the VM itself. (I.e. I create an ASP.NET solution on the VM and try to publish it.) :-(